# issue with videoPlayer in iphone-titanium

Tags: iphone, video, titanium

I'm playing a video in titanium-iphone and I created the videoPlayer like this:

```
   var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
    url: contentURL,
    backgroundColor:'#111',
    scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FILL
   });
```

And it looks like this:

[image: enter image description]

The problem is that I have no control on the bottom time bar of the movie. It appears instantly and dismisses after a few seconds. Is there a way to make it not appear when the video opens and appear only when I click on the video and dissappear at the next click???!???

Thank you!

Comment: =)))...any idea how to solve the issue!

Comment: i dont use titanium btw.. sorry

Comment: @adrian: hi, where is image ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set `mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT`

Use below code : -

```
var contentURL = "http://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp4/twit.cachefly.net/video/aaa/aaa0033/aaa0033_h264b_640x368_256.mp4";

var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({      
        title:'Test',
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        layout: 'vertical'
});

var movie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer
({
    url:contentURL,
    top : 2,
    autoplay : true,
    height : 300,
    width : 300,
    mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
    scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT
});
win.add(movie);
```